# Geometric mean in Ruby returning Infinity for large arrays

Tags: ruby, math, mean

I am trying to calculate the geometric mean of an array in Ruby.  However, after the array grows to a certain size it starts to return `Infinity` for the calculation of the geometric mean.  Any idea of what is causing this to happen, or a better way to calculate the geometric mean of larger arrays in Ruby?

ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

**Example**

```
def gmean(x)
  prod=1.0
  x.each {|v| prod *= v}
  prod**(1.0/x.size)
end 

sample_array = [1, 1, 1, 1200, 1483, 1827, 2114, 2163, 2231, 2313, 2368, 2636, 2736, 2834, 2847, 2985, 3225, 3304, 3317, 3439, 3519, 3586, 3607, 3611, 3722, 3770, 4346, 4383, 4392, 4548, 4639, 4773, 4836, 4929, 4991, 4998, 5075, 5078, 5433, 5549, 5727, 5908, 5911, 5989, 6007, 6031, 6065, 6097, 6141, 6654, 6915, 6969, 6972, 7074, 7257, 7260, 7342, 7526, 7550, 7898, 8032, 8037, 8265, 8567, 8888, 9033, 9169, 9412, 9701, 9962, 10247, 11209, 14069, 14741, 15088, 15511, 18775, 19755, 19937, 24064, 32437, 41372, 59057, 778335]
puts gmean(sample_array)
puts sample_array.inject{|sum,x| sum + x }
puts sample_array.length

#=> 4672.4331716807965
#=> 1429766
#=> 84

sample_array2 = [1, 1, 2, 1200, 1483, 1827, 2114, 2163, 2231, 2313, 2368, 2636, 2736, 2834, 2847, 2985, 3225, 3304, 3317, 3439, 3519, 3586, 3607, 3611, 3722, 3770, 4346, 4383, 4392, 4548, 4639, 4773, 4836, 4929, 4991, 4998, 5075, 5078, 5433, 5549, 5727, 5908, 5911, 5989, 6007, 6031, 6065, 6097, 6141, 6654, 6915, 6969, 6972, 7074, 7257, 7260, 7342, 7526, 7550, 7898, 8032, 8037, 8265, 8567, 8888, 9033, 9169, 9412, 9701, 9962, 10247, 11209, 14069, 14741, 15088, 15511, 18775, 19755, 19937, 24064, 32437, 41372, 59057, 778335]
puts gmean(sample_array2)
puts sample_array2.inject{|sum,x| sum + x }
puts sample_array2.length

#=> Infinity
#=> 1429767
#=> 84
```

Comment: Where is the `geometric` method defined? You have `gmean` defined… perhaps that’s what you mean?

Comment: Sorry, typo. I'll edit the above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your value is overflowing what a `Float` can hold. Instead consider using [`BigDecimal`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html):

```
require 'bigdecimal'

def gmean(x)
  prod = BigDecimal.new 1
  x.each { |v| prod *= BigDecimal.new(v) }
  prod ** (1.0 / x.size)
end

gmean(sample_array2).to_f  #=> 4711.148446895203
```

Note that your method can be simplified to a more functional style:

```
def gmean(xs)
  one = BigDecimal.new 1
  xs.map { |x| BigDecimal.new x }.inject(one, :*) ** (one / xs.size)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, that gives me the following error: `'**': #<Class:0x0000010108e6f0> can't be coerced into BigDecimal (TypeError)`

Comment: @diasks2 Whoops, should be fixed.

Answer (score 7):

If `BigDecimal`s end up taking too much memory, you can take advantage of logarithms:

```
def gmean(x)
  sum = x.inject(0) { |memo, v| memo + Math.log(v) }
  sum /= x.size
  Math.exp(sum).round(2)
end
```

Comment: Nice, +1. Though this will, of course, be less precise than using a BigDecimal for all the usual reasons Floats are imprecise.

Comment: Helped me finding the arithmetic mean for a large array. +1 But note that there is a difference between arithmetic mean and geometric mean. Maybe your method should be named _amean(x)_

Comment: The arithmetic mean is the regular mean: (a+b)/2. What this function returns is the geometric mean, sqrt(ab).